# Using externals on webpack without script loading

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-5

I am having issues with a specific library not working because apparently I have 2 instances of react, one for my library component and another for my main app.

Currently, my components library uses `react` and `react-dom` as deps on `package.json`, BUT have them both added as peer-deps.

In order to solve this I've added

```
externals: {
  react: 'react',
  'react-dom': 'react-dom',
},
```

To my main app webpack, but now I need to add `react` as an external load (like a new `script` tag on my main `index.html`). Is there a way for me to not have 2 instances of react while still using the instance from my main (and not require a new `script` tag)?

I am currently using `webpack5` and `react17`